# Installing Ionic 2 and 3 on same machine

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

We have several ionic projects and are not keen on upgrading all of our ionic 2 projects to 3 just yet. Can I install both versions of Ionic (and I assume the relevant Cordova) on the same machine and then specify which one to use when building an individual project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can work on Ionic 2 and Ionic 3 projects at the same time on the same machine, because the dependencies of each project are listed in the `package.json` file, so when you run `npm install` the right version of each dependency will be installed in each project.

The same happens with cordova plugins, since the installed version of each plugin is stored in the `package.json` and `config.xml` files, so when adding platforms or updating plugins the right version will be used for each project.

Besides that, the `Ionic CLI` allows you to work with Ionic 2 and Ionic 3 projects at the same time (it even allows you to work in Ionic v1 projects) so **you won't have any problems when working on Ionic 2 and Ionic 3 projects in the same machine**.

Comment: Thx for this answer.

Comment: Glad to see that it helped @bletch :)